# Need to have a table containing requests associated with date

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I can't get this result: I need to have a date table (in YYYY-MM-DD format), where each date would contain requests.
Let me explain, basically I browse an already existing date table, which contains the dates of my requests.
And after this date array browsing, I build my new array which contains the date on which the array is positioned, as a key, and the associated request obtained by the call to my API.

So I have an array of the style (in the code snippet, dateArray[i] corresponds to the date on which the date array is positioned):

Here is the table daysRequests:

```js
[{
date: dateArray[i],
requests: [idRequestX]
},
{
date: dateArray[i],
requests: [idRequestX, idRequestY]
}]
```

And here is the push I do there:

```js
this.daysRequests.push({
     day: dateArray[i],
     requests: [idRequest]
});
```

Currently the push in the array creates duplicates for me, because if a date has several requests, it is not able to look for the record in the array corresponding to the already existing date and add in the requests sub-array, the new request.

I don't know how to check that the date already exists in the table and if it does, add the id of the new request in its sub table.

The complexity is that it is a key-value dictionary containing an array.

And that, I can't manage.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Yes, sorry it's a bit confusing.
Basically, these code snippets that I provided, should be used to fill a table (called daysRequests) from the dates of each request.
But the requests themselves do not contain all the dates, in fact they contain a start date and an end date of the request.
So, a method that I have created, returns an array (called dateArray) of all the dates between the start and end date of a request.
So for each date obtained in the array generated by the method, I fill my daysRequests array with the push given in the extract above.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to search for the item with the same date. If it doesn't exist you can push the object, if it exists then push just the `idRequest` to `requests`.

```
const index=this.daysRequest.findIndex((item) => item.day===dateArray[i]);
if (index==-1){ //index is -1 if the item isn't found
    this.daysRequest.push({
        day: dateArray[i],
        requests: [idRequest]
    });
}else{  //index is the index of daysRequest where your date is
    this.daysRequest[index].requests.push(idRequest);
}
```

Have a look at the docs: [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Answer (score 0):

@ojovirtual
In fact, I tried a very similar solution, but I get the same thing as yours, namely that in the table displayed in the console, I have duplicates.
Here is my use of your code in my loop, I use the i variable in the loop for the index of daysRequest in the else:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {
    const index=this.daysRequest.findIndex((item) => item.day===dateArray[i]) ;
    if (index==-1){ //index is -1 if the item is not found
        this.daysRequest.push({
        day : dateArray[i],
        requests : [idRequest]
        }) ;
    }else{ //index is the index of daysRequest where your date is located
        this.daysRequest[i].requests.push(idRequest) ;
    }

    console.log(this.daysRequest.toString()) ;
}
```

[image: Console log]

We can see that the day "Mon Nov 14 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100" is duplicated, but with 2 different requests, instead of being combined

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [`Array.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method along with [`Destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) operator.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const arr = [{
  date: '15-11-2022',
  requests: [1]
}, {
  date: '10-11-2022',
  requests: [1, 3]
}];

const objToPush = {
    date: '15-11-2022',
  requests: [5]
};

const index = arr.findIndex(item => item.date === objToPush.date);

if (index === -1) {
    arr.push(objToPush);
} else {
    arr[index].requests = [...arr[index].requests, ...objToPush.requests]
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Same as with @ojovirtual's solution, it still creates duplicates :(

Comment: It should not create duplicates. Can you please try the above solution and try to find out the root cause.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer, I tried the solution as you provided it, but it creates duplicates all the same :(

Comment: Can you please share your code in a jsfiddle or codepen link ? So that i can look into that and try to find the loop hole.

Comment: Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/5oxb92uc/

Comment: @ArzelPRO This fiddle is having issue with `dateArray`. It is returning an array of objects which returns a function. Can you please simplify it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see how to simplify it, since that's what I need. And it allows me to get the table of dates between the start date of the request and the end date of the request

Comment: @ArzelPRO Can you just paste your `dateArray` and the object which you are going to `update` or `push`. I can help by looking into that

Comment: I don't have a ready-made dateArray, it is automatically generated by the getDates() method, by passing the start date of the request and the end date of the request as parameters.
On the other hand, the object to which I'm going to push or update is this empty array: daysRequests: [], which will be filled with the code I've provided.
In fact, it is a declared but empty array, in the data() section of VueJS

So after I make this.daysDemands.push() but it creates duplicates :(

Comment: @ArzelPRO If your dateArr contains same data structure as `arr` and  in my code snippet. Then things should work fine. I am just trying to understand that structure.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this :

```js
const day = dateArray[i];
 
if (!(day in this.daysRequests)) {
    // if there is no request for this day yet
    this.daysRequests[day] = [];
}
 
this.daysRequests[day].push(request_id);
```

works very well, it makes me an object where each property is a list of requests.